# Is the nvidia gtx 690 and the ryzen 5 1600 cpu compatible with ubuntu 18.04 LTS?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nvidia, gpu, amd

it is my first post on this forum i hope that i did not create any confussions.

I have already built this pc:

```
NVIDIA GTX 690
X370 MSI MOTHERBOARD
AMD RYZEN 5 1600
16GB DDR4
planning to install Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
```

i'm gonna make 4 questions

**1- Is the Nvidia GTX 690 compatible with linux/ubuntu 18.04 LTS ?**

i am asking that question because i have heard a few rumours that the gtx 690 actually has compatilibility issues because it is a dual GPU (Two underclocked 680).

i could not find any answer to this question in others website.

**2-Does the ryzen 5 1600 have any compatibility issue with linux/ubuntu 18.04 LTS** ?

I also made this question because i have seen in other forums "which got me confused" that the ryzen platform is buggy on linux.

**3- (If the gpu does not have any issue) Would i get better perfomance if i install ubuntu instead of windows?**

I'm also planning to do 3d modeling with blender. i made this question because i would really like to know how that GPU performs on ubuntu.

**4- (If the gpu does not have any issue) What is the best nvidia driver version recommended for the gtx 690 on ubuntu 18.40 LTS?**

I hope that i'll get out of doubts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. [Yes](https://www.nvidia.com/Download/driverResults.aspx/81252/en-us)
2. Some of the very first series were, but all of them are RMA-able and AMD will replace them free of charge if you contact them.
3. it's a long time ago since [Linus Torvalds complained about nVidia](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iYWzMvlj2RQ). Performance should be identical for both.
4. See #1

Comment: ***Note:** This is not a forum:*  your questions will be much better served in the future if you as one question per... well... question!  **;-)**

Comment: wow, thanks but recently i have found this driver version: **430.34**.
so will the **346.35** version  make the GPU faster than the  **430.34**. version?.